# Pandas: Aggregation with Weights

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

For now, I am computing my moments using something along the lines of

```
moments = df_sum.groupby(level=[0,1])['myCol'].agg([np.min, np.median, np.mean, np.max, np.std, len])
```

However, now I have an additional column `weights` that contains the corresponding weights. That is, if a weight of a column is `2`, the observation should count twice when computing mean, std etc. I would like to repeat my computations using the `weights` column. A brute force way would be to repeat my observations using `weights`, but:

- This would be quite slow and inefficient
- Weights are not necessarily integer

Many statistical functions contain a parameters to append the computation weights, for example [np.average](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html):

> weights : array_like, optional An array of weights associated with the
>   values in a. Each value in a contributes to the average according to
>   its associated weight. The weights array can either be 1-D (in which
>   case its length must be the size of a along the given axis) or of the
>   same shape as a. If weights=None, then all data in a are assumed to
>   have a weight equal to one.

Given that I would like to include functions such as `np.average`, how would I have to rephrase my command from above? And are there commands for other aggregation functions such as `median`? Trivially, `min` and `max` shouldn't change, and computing `len()` shouldn't be too difficult either.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do this ahead of the groupby?

```
df_sum['weighted_col'] = df_sum['weights'] * df_sum['my_col']
df.groupby(level=[0, 1].agg([...])[<columns to keep>]
```

Also, pro-tip: with everything that you're computing with your `groupby`, it'd be easier to just do this:

`df.groupby(level=[0, 1].apply(lambda g: g.describe().T)`

Comment: you can directly use .describe() on a groupby btw

Comment: directly affecting the values works with `mean,` but not with `std`, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @FooBar -- the weighted standard deviation might be a little more complicated http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/how-do-i-calculate-a-weighted-standard-deviation-in-excel